# AES subkey generation operations order

Tags: aes

I am preparing for my Information Security state exam. There is a question in preparation sheet that asks about order of operations to generate subkey for AES algorithm.

Operations listed:

1. XOR with constant
2. XOR with first 4 bytes of subkey
3. s-box
4. Circular left shift

I tried to google this question, but didn't find the answer. What is the right order?

Comment: Did you take a look at section 5.2 "Key Expansion" in the [standard](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips197/fips-197.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "key expansion" or subkey generation in AES is an iterative process. Due to some work I am doing about this block cipher I have prepared an figure that may help you:

[image: Rijndael's key expansion]

The algorithm is checking if the iterator of the generator is in congruent with 0 *modulo #columns* to proceed with 3 operations or only with one if is not.

The rotWord() is a circular shift (I think is to the right), the call to subBytes() uses the SBox and RCon in the bottom is an operation in the polynomial field.

I hope this will help to find out yourself the answer for your test, without giving you the answer directly.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I think that I got idea how it works.